# Como mudar o endereço do host para onde vão os requests "src" e "href"?

Tags: php, http

Exemplo: eu dou um `file_get_contents('http://youtube.com')` e então, caso nos `src` e `href` do html não tiverem o caminho inteiro, e sim apenas `src="/pasta/arquivo.ext"`, ao invés de `src="https://youtube.com/pasta/arquivo.ext"`, os requests irão dar todos `404 not found`, pois ele vai buscar no meu servidor (localhost).

Existe algum parâmetro do `header http` que eu possa mudar para indicar para onde eu quero que vá esses requests? Eu tentei reescrever e colocar o path inteiro nas referências, por meio de `str_replace()`, mas não adianta, porque os arquivos javascript fazem requisição para o servidor local (localhost) e atrapalha o funcionamento do mesmo jeito. Não dá para ficar baixando tudo e e reescrevendo; eu queria mudar isso no header http (acho que é possível)

O YouTube foi somente a nível de exemplo. Não quero copiar o site e sim fazer modificações no css do player embed. (não quero libs, estou fazendo isso como um exercício)

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

O termo certo seria "transformar url relativa em url absoluta".

Verifique se a URL possui http no início da string. Se não possuir é provavelmente uma URL relativa.

```
$domain = 'https://dominio/';
$url = '/pasta/arquivo.txt';

$url = ltrim($url, '/'); //remove barra inicial, caso exista.
if (substr($url, 0, 4) != 'http') {
    $url = $domain.$str; // concatena ao domínio
}

echo $url;
```

Se quiser, adicione mais consitência pois é apenas verificado se existe “http” no começo da string mas se encontrar uma URL absoluta com protocolo diferente do "http" como "ftp://" por exemplo, terá uma URL inválida.

Uma técnica é verificar se dentro dos primeiros 12 caracteres contém `://`.

Caso exista `://` e o início for diferente de `http`, ignore a URL inteira ou faça outra ação que desejar.

Comment: Também pode usar `parse_url` e se não encontrar o *host* é uma url relativa.

Comment: Eu estava falando de mudar o entendimento do browser acerca do host real do endereço relativo. Desse jeito aí, eu teria que dar replace em todo o html, certo? Se for assim, não serve. Mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Então não está claro o que pede. Descreva melhor se não será fechada a pergunta. @inovapixel

Comment: @DanielOmine resumo: o que eu quero é fazer o browser entender que o endereço é relativo a outro site que eu queira. Quero saber se dá para fazer isso no header HTTP, de request ou response, não sei. Entendeu? Quero que quando o site for omitido do href ou src, o browser associe o "URL relativo" a algum site que eu queira, e não ao da barra de endereços...

Comment: Descreva na pergunta, mas ainda assim está confuso. Que papo é esse de browser?  Ou eu estou muito lerdo da cabeça para pescar o que quer fazer ou está mesmo confuso.. rsr  Tente desenhar, faz uma ilustração e coisas do tipo. O `str_replace()` nem é necessário. Basta prefixar o domínio as URLs que encontrar.  Não entendi o trecho onde embolou tudo no JavaScript e localhost. O que raios quer dizer aquilo?  rsrs  Descreva isso na pergunta e não aqui no comentário pois aqui não tem espaço adequado. @inovapixel

Comment: @DanielOmine, pelo que eu entendi - *talvez* - o que ele queira se aproxime da tag `<base>` para arquivos relativos.